# Query mySql INSERT não retorna nada, mesmo após

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js

Eu recentemente comecei a usar node e eu estou meio que com um probleminha.

Eu estou tentando dar um INSERT de um produto na minha tabela "produtos" mas não coloquei auto-increment no ID dele, então para salvar o ID certo estou usando primeiro um "SELECT MAX", algo como:

```
router.post('/', (req, res) => {
    const { produto_descricao, produto_preco_venda, produto_marca}
    conn.query('SELECT MAX(id_produto) as id_produto FROM produtos', (error, results) => {
       if (error) res.json(error);

       let id_max = results[0].id_product
       id_max = id_max === null ? 1 : id_max + 1;

       conn.query(
          `INSERT INTO produtos (id_produto, produto_descricao, produto_preco_venda, produto_marca) VALUES ('${id_max}', '${produto_descricao}', '${produto_preco_venda}', '${produto_marca}')`,
          (error, results) => {
           if (error) res.json(error);

          res.json({ message: "Everything ok!" })
      })`
   })
})
```

E então estou executando outra query dentro da anterior para de fato dar o INSERT no banco de dados.

Porém esse código grava no banco de dados normalmente, porém é como se o `res.json({ message: "Everything ok!" })` fosse ignorado, ele não retorna nada.

O que estou fazendo de errado?

Comment: Tenta colocando um **return** no `res.json({ message: "Everything ok!" })` e se possível  coloca o **if** com `{ }` passando o error como fez e na linha debaixo insere um return dentro do if tbm.

Comment: Infelizmente não resolveu. Ainda sim ele grava no banco mas nada de resposta. :/

Comment: `SELECT MAX(id_produto) as id_produto` mas quando você lê `results[0].id_product`, já aqui ta errado é id_produto ou id_product? Além deste, o que são aquelas constantes declaradas no inicio que não prendem nenhum valor?

Comment: É id_produto, escrevi errado na hora de fazer a pergunta. as constantes pegam o valor do body e estão sendo enviadas no INSERT.....